# Can not understand setState(int[]) method in Drawable in Android

Tags: android

I saw in android documentation that setState(int[]) method in Drawble class returns a boolean value. on other occasion I found some code like this:

```
        mSelectionHighlight =context.getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.list_selector_background);
        mSelectionHighlight.setState(new int[] {
        android.R.attr.state_enabled,
        android.R.attr.state_focused,
        android.R.attr.state_window_focused,
        android.R.attr.state_pressed});
```

Shouldn't it be

```
        someBoolean=mSelectionHighlight.setState(new int[] {
        android.R.attr.state_enabled,
        android.R.attr.state_focused,
        android.R.attr.state_window_focused,
        android.R.attr.state_pressed});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo do not have to assign the return value of a method call to a variable. You can simply call the method and ignore the return value.

Comment: This is a behavior of Java, not Android specifically. There are probably many places where you have done exactly this. If you've ever called `arrayList.add(object)` for example, you've just called a method and ignored its return value (`add` returns a boolean whether the collection was modified).